# cross-browser vertical centering outer divs of 3-items horizontal resizing array

Tags: html, cross-browser, alignment

I am trying to create a simple, self-contained responsive page featuring three columns of content. The center one has a full-height image, the outer ones have basic html content (paragraphs of text and one image). The outer columns content should be vertically centered in the visible window.

This code does everything it needs except vertically centering the content of the outer (leftmost and rightmost) divs. Basically, content stays stuck on top... any suggestion (possibly with actual code, since I am a newbie)? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>title</title>
<style>
.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 99vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
 -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;   
}

.wrap-item{
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;       
}

.wrap-img{
    width: 33%;
  height: 100vh;      
}

#im {
    background-image: url("url");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
.auto-style1 {
    border-width: 0px;
}
</style>    
</head>    
<body>    
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="wrap-item" style="vertical-align:middle">                   
            <p>content </p>     
        </div>
        <div class="wrap-item" id="im"></div>
        <div class="wrap-item" style="vertical-align:middle">               
            <p>content</p>
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

the changes I made were to give `div#im` the class `.wrap-img` instead of `.wrap-item`. Also I removed the property `height:100%` from `.wrap-item`, so that the wrap-item divs are only as tall as their contents.

Note: I gave `#im` a red background so you can see it.

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 99vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
 -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;   
}

.wrap-item{
  width: 33%;
  display: inline-block;       
}

.wrap-img{
    width: 33%;
  height: 100vh; 
  display:inline-block;
}

#im {
    background-image: url("url");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background:#f00;
}
.auto-style1 {
    border-width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>title</title>    
</head>    
<body>    
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="wrap-item" style="vertical-align:middle">
            <p>content</p>     
        </div>
        <div class="wrap-img" id="im">
        </div>
        <div class="wrap-item" style="vertical-align:middle">      
            <p>content</p>
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```